# How do you use a custom class as a property of an entity with a conversion with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to model various levels of accounts using "Table Per Hierarchy" in my application. Basically there are 3 levels of account: Super, Partner and Standard. They all share most of their properties, but the key difference is that Standard accounts are managed by a Super or Partner account.

I want to add an `AccountType` property to the `Account` base class that is a custom class, but is persisted to the database as a string. I know you can add a conversion for properties via EF's fluent API, but I cannot get it to work for this scenario.

This is how my classes are laid out:

```
public abstract class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public AccountTypeClass AccountType { get; set; }

    // other props omitted for brevity
}

public class StandardAccount : Account
{
    [Required]
    public int ManagingAccountId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ManagingAccountId))]
    public ManagingAccount ManagingAccount { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ManagingAccount : Account
{
    public ICollection<StandardAccount> Accounts { get; set; } = new List<StandardAccount>();
}

public class PartnerAccount : ManagingAccount { }

public class SuperAccount : ManagingAccount { }

public class AccountTypeClass
{
    // other props omitted for brevity

    private string value;

    private AccountTypeClass(string value) => this.value = value;

    public static AccountTypeClass Super => new AccountTypeClass(nameof(Super).ToLower());
    public static AccountTypeClass Partner => new AccountTypeClass(nameof(Partner).ToLower());
    public static AccountTypeClass Standard => new AccountTypeClass(nameof(Standard).ToLower());

    public static AccountTypeClass Parse(string value)
    {
        switch(value)
        {
            case "super": return Super;
            case "partner": return Partner;
            case "standard": return Standard;
            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() => this.value;
}
```

And this is my `DbContext`:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder
            .Entity<Account>()
            .Property(p => p.AccountType)                    
            .HasConversion(p => p.ToString(), p => AccountTypeClass.Parse(p));

        builder.Entity<SuperAccount>().HasData(new SuperAccount() { Id = 1 });
        builder.Entity<PartnerAccount>().HasData(new PartnerAccount() { Id = 2 });
        builder.Entity<StandardAccount>().HasData(new StandardAccount() { Id = 3, ManagingAccountId = 1 });
    }
}
```

When I try and add a migration I get the following error message:

> The property or navigation 'AccountType' cannot be added to the entity type 'ManagingAccount' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Account'.

But if I swap out the `AccountTypeClass` for this enum:

```
public enum AccountTypeEnum { Super, Partner, Standard }
```

And change the conversion to this (Where `EnumHelper` is just a little helper class that parses a string to an enum value):

```
builder
    .Entity<Account>()
    .Property(p => p.AccountType)                    
    .HasConversion(p => p.ToString(), p => EnumHelper.Parse<AccountTypeEnum>(p));
```

Everything works as expected.

I can get the conversion to/from my `AccountTypeClass` to work on a standalone class (no inheritance), but not when I try using inheritance and table per hierarchy. Is this not supported or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Can you use Complex types as columns in the way you were doing? I'm honestly not sure. As far as I know they can only be used for navigation properties.
That it works when using enums possibly indicates that you can't and that the error message is unclear.

Comment: Yes, you definitely can, add long as your conversion go to and from a type supported in the database. It's entirely possible I'm abusing it in a way that's not intended though I suppose...

Comment: Looks like I'll have to read up on that :-) Interesting question though, curious about the answer

Comment: This probably is a current EF Core shortcoming (bug) **similar** to the ones mentioned for [owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings): *"Inheritance hierarchies that include owned entity types are not supported"* and "*Instances of owned entity types cannot be shared by multiple owners (this is a well-known scenario for value objects that cannot be implemented using owned entity types)*"

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I feel like your migrations are messed up right now. Have you tried deleting all your migrations and creating a fresh initial migration, just to verify your model is translatable?

Comment: This is a super old question (.NET Core 2.1, even though it doesn't say that anywhere). The project in question is now on .NET 6 and doesn't have the same problem. I believe I just ended up going with a standard enum property to work around the limitation though. I don't think that migrations were to blame because I created a minimal reproduction consisting of essentially just the code in my question  and a single migration.